# Can't get Jest to work together with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, babel-jest

I've problems getting [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) to work together with [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation). I've created a new project following the instructions in the [react-navigation guidelines](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/), and then added Jest and configured exactly as detailed below. The app runs fine, but when I run the tests I encounter the following error:

```
React caught an error thrown by NavigationContainer. You should fix this error in your code. Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

  The error is located at: 
      in NavigationContainer (created by App)
      in App

  The error was thrown at: 
      at NavigationContainer.componentDidMount (/Users/gustav/kicksort/albert/albertReact1/node_modules/react-navigation/src/createNavigationContainer.js:189:2171)
      at commitLifeCycles (/Users/gustav/kicksort/albert/albertReact1/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberCommitWork.js:421:24),
      ...
      ...
```

Here are the relevant contents of my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-dom": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-native": "0.44.0",
  "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.2",
  "enzyme": "2.8.2",
  "jest": "20.0.3",
  "jest-cli": "20.0.3",
  "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
  ]
}
```

Here's my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": ["react-native"],
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
      }
   }
}
```

And finally __mocks__/react-native.js:

```
const rn = require('react-native')
jest.mock('Linking', () => {
  return {
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    openURL: jest.fn(),
    canOpenURL: jest.fn(),
    getInitialURL: jest.fn(),
  }
})
module.exports = rn;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I wrote in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "__coverage__",
    "testRegex": "./__tests__/[^setup].*.js$",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric)"],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__tests__/setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

I have a folder names "__test__" and under it is a setup.js file to control all the component I mocked:

```
//setup.js
jest.mock('Linking', () => {
    return {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        openURL: jest.fn(),
        canOpenURL: jest.fn(),
        getInitialURL: jest.fn(),
    }
})

jest.mock('react-native-fabric', () => {
    return {
        Crashlytics: {
            crash: () => {},
        },
        Answers: {
            logCustom: () => {},
            logContentView: () => {},
        },
    }
})

jest.mock('WebView', () => 'WebView');

jest.mock('DatePickerIOS', () => 'DatePickerIOS');
```

Comment: Thank you, still the same error though. Can I see your whole package.json file please?

Comment: I have "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.9" in my "dependencies" also.

Comment: I have that as well (updated my question to show it now), any other dependencies that you have different version than mine maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem. But I was able to fix it by looking into the source code and found it's calling

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(
  (url: string) => url && this._handleOpenURL(url)
);
```

So it can be fixed by

```
jest.mock('Linking', () => {

  // we need to mock both Linking.getInitialURL() 
  // and Linking.getInitialURL().then()
  const getInitialURL = jest.fn()
  getInitialURL.mockReturnValueOnce({then: jest.fn()})

  return {
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    openURL: jest.fn(),
    canOpenURL: jest.fn(),
    getInitialURL: getInitialURL
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest fix is to use [react-native-jest-mocks](https://github.com/Xabadu/react-native-jest-mocks). Just follow its instructions.